# Android Spinner throwing a Java.lang.nullpointerexception - Android Beginner

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-intent, nullpointerexception

I am a beginner so please bear with me. I have created an app with a spinner that controls the visibility of Edit Texts. When I run this application, a catch statement catches a null point exception and the spinner is not populated with my string array. Any ideas or help?

Here is my code

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        try {

        player1.findViewById(R.id.editTextPlayer1);
        player2.findViewById(R.id.editTextPlayer2);
        player3.findViewById(R.id.editTextPlayer3);
        player4.findViewById(R.id.editTextPlayer4);
        player5.findViewById(R.id.editTextPlayer5);
        player6.findViewById(R.id.editTextPlayer6);
        player7.findViewById(R.id.editTextPlayer7);
        player8.findViewById(R.id.editTextPlayer8);

        Spinner spinner = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinnerplayers);

        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
                this, R.array.peoplearray, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spinner.setAdapter(adapter);

        spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
        }catch (Exception e) {

            // handle any errors

            Log.e("TestActivity", "Error in activity", e);  // log the error

            // Also let the user know something went wrong

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.getClass().getName() + " " + e.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int pos,
            long id) {
            numberOfPlayers = pos + 2;

        switch(pos){
        case 0:
            player1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            player2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            break;
        case 1:
            player1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            player2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            player3.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            break;
        case 2:
            player1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            player2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            player3.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            player4.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            break;
        case 3:         
            player1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            player2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            player3.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            player4.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            player5.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            break;
        case 4:
            player1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            player2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            player3.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            player4.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            player5.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            player6.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            break;
        case 5:
            player1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            player2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            player3.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            player4.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            player5.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            player6.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            player7.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            break;
        case 6:
            player1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            player2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            player3.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            player4.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            player5.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            player6.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            player7.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            player8.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            break;
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
    }
```

Here is the logcat error:

```
06-05 15:10:03.986: E/TestActivity(1815): Error in activity
06-05 15:10:03.986: E/TestActivity(1815): java.lang.NullPointerException
06-05 15:10:03.986: E/TestActivity(1815):   at com.brightdesign.truthordare.Main.onCreate(Main.java:42)
06-05 15:10:03.986: E/TestActivity(1815):   at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
06-05 15:10:03.986: E/TestActivity(1815):   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
06-05 15:10:03.986: E/TestActivity(1815):   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1920)
06-05 15:10:03.986: E/TestActivity(1815):   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981)
06-05 15:10:03.986: E/TestActivity(1815):   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123)
06-05 15:10:03.986: E/TestActivity(1815):   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147)
06-05 15:10:03.986: E/TestActivity(1815):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-05 15:10:03.986: E/TestActivity(1815):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
06-05 15:10:03.986: E/TestActivity(1815):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
06-05 15:10:03.986: E/TestActivity(1815):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-05 15:10:03.986: E/TestActivity(1815):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
06-05 15:10:03.986: E/TestActivity(1815):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
06-05 15:10:03.986: E/TestActivity(1815):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
06-05 15:10:03.986: E/TestActivity(1815):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Are you sure there is an entry corresponding to the spinner in your `XML`?

Comment: I am pretty sure... but eclipse has been acting pretty weird and gave random errors in the xml before, not to mention the weird symbols that eclipse replaced with spaces and line breaks

Answer (score 2):

**Replace**

```
    Spinner spinner = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinnerplayers);  
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
            this, R.array.peoplearray, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
```

**By This**

```
    Spinner spinner = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinnerplayers);
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, getResources().getStringArray(R.array.peoplearray))
    spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: This advice helps me. If you still get NullPointerException you should try to find out what context do you need to get proper resources.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you did not get null  in this statement.

```
Spinner spinner = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinnerplayers);
```

You can clean the project and then again rebuild. It might solve your problem.